# Callback function not working in rails before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following in the model:

```
before_save :set_defaults

def set_defaults
  self.num_results ||= 5
end
```

And I create the object in my controller like this:

```
Search.create!(  :keyword        => params[:keyword],
                 :ip_address     => request.remote_ip,
                 :referring_page => request.referer )
```

Even though I haven't set a value for `num_results` it's still getting saved as `0` (which is the default value in the DB schema). The callback function doesn't get called at all. Any clues?

**Update:**

I turns out the callback does get called, the problem is in:

`self.num_results ||= 5`

**How would I set the default value in ruby?** As this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

num_results is only set to 5, if num_result is nil. In your case it is set to 0 by default, so the assignemt does not do anything. Try to change your assignment to:

```
self.num_results = 5
```

Comment: But I don't set the 0 in the model anywhere (that is only present on the db schema definition). Is there a way to put a value if nothing has been explicitly been set?

Comment: If you defined a default value within your migration than this default value is set, when the object ist initialized. You don´t have to set it in your model again.